# Magento - Uses and Benefits of getOptionsByCode

Tags: magento

I have seen that Magento uses this method "`getOptionsByCode()`" in the class "`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`" a lot, for retrieving / fetching the Quote Item options by code. After printing each of the Options, for any item, I found these:-

- `info_buyRequest`
- `option_ids`
- `option_1843`
- `attributes`
- `product_qty_231`
- `simple_product`

Now here are my questions:-

1. What Magento is trying to achieve with the use of this method "`getOptionsByCode()`", or its benefits?
2. Is this only to be used for the Configurable Products, or for other composite Product Types also?
3. How to determine which option codes are for Custom Options of the corresponding Product Item?
4. What are the options "`info_buyRequest`" and "`simple_product`" specifically used for?
5. Are there any other uses of the Custom Options, like Configurable Attributes or something else?

Comment: For anybody interested in a detailed reference about the options of `info_buyRequest` and how they are used, look here: http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-info_buyrequest-objekt-referenz/

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer one at a time:

1. The item's options are the values the user selected for adding that product to the cart (for instance, the different options and their selected values).
2. All of the products use at least the info_buyRequest option. I don't really know about the other ones.
3. I think they might be all inside of the "attributes" option, but I never really used custom options.
4. info_buyRequest is used to spec the qty, and all other options. It is the initial request (that later gets processed). The simple product probably is the real product you are adding to the cart (that is, the item might be a configurable product, but you add in the cart a simple product).
5. I don't really know. But, if what you need is to find out the options chosen for such product, my guess is you should check either the "attributes" option, or just get the simple_product and get it's options.